# Garbled characters when sniff the http data and store them using pcap

Tags: c, http, tcp, libpcap

I filter it with "port 80" and start to catch using `pcap_loop(phandle,-1,pcap_callback,NULL);`

```
the pcap_callback function

void pcap_callback(u_char* user,const struct pcap_pkthdr* header, const u_char* pkt_data){

   FILE *fp=fopen("1.html","a"); 

   ether_header * eheader=(ether_header*)pkt_data;

   if(eheader->ether_type==htons(ETHERTYPE_IP)){
     ip_header* ih=(ip_header*)(pkt_data+14);

    if(ih->proto==htons(TCP_PROTOCAL)){
      int ip_len=ntohs(ih->tlen);     
      int find_http=false;
      char* ip_pkt_data=(char*)ih;
      int n=0;
      char buffer[BUFFER_MAX_LENGTH];
      int bufsize=0;

      for(;n<ip_len;n++)
   {
     /* http get or post request */
     if(!find_http && ((n+3<ip_len && strncmp(ip_pkt_data+n,"GET",strlen("GET")) ==0 )
            || (n+4<ip_len && strncmp(ip_pkt_data+n,"POST",strlen("POST")) == 0)) )
      find_http = true;

    /* http response */
     if(!find_http && n+8<ip_len && strncmp(ip_pkt_data+n,"HTTP/1.1",strlen("HTTP/1.1"))==0)
      find_http = true;

  /* if http is found */
    if(find_http)
      {
        buffer[bufsize] = ip_pkt_data[n]; /* copy http data to buffer */
        bufsize ++;
      }
   }
     /* print http content */
     if(find_http) {
   buffer[bufsize] = '\0';
   printf("%s\n", buffer);
   printf("\n**********************************************\n\n");
   int i=0;
   char c;
   for(i=0;i<bufsize;i++)
    {
      c=buffer[i];
      fputc(c,fp);
    }
   fclose(fp);
      }
    }
  }
 }
```

And i run it , and visit Google.com

It can only print the request/response headers at the screen, sometimes with one or two wired characters(a little box within four numbers(1 or 0)). So ,i store them to a html file, but it is still a mess. If `cat 1.html` at shell, the data after response headers would be multiple lines, some of them are show in a white background and stick together.

If open it in Emacs, it will display something like this `^@^@^S\234\252`.If i paste them here, they would show difference. 
I guess maybe it it the picture or other file like gif or something course the problem, because i sometimes the response headers show `Content-Type: image/png`.
But when it is `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`, it is also a mess.

Why? And how to solve it?

Thanks!!

Comment: What does the `Content-Encoding` header of the response say (if present)?

Comment: `Content-Encoding: gzip`. Is that means i need to decode it?

Comment: It means that the content is compressed, so you would expect it to be "garbled", as you put it. It needs to be decompressed before you can read the plain-text content, the command `gzip -d /path/to/file` should do this for you as long as the file only contains the body of the response.